# Change the values in one data set based on the values in another

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have the following problem:

```
names <- c("Peter", "Gabriel", "James", "Philip")
city <- c("LA", "NY","Chicago","Chicago")
number <- seq(1, length(names))

from <- c("Peter", "Peter", "Gabriel", "James", "James")
to <- c("James","Gabriel", "Philip", "Gabriel", "Philip")

nodes <- data.frame(names, city, number)
edges <- data.frame(from, to)
```

How do I change the values of `edges$from` to match those in `nodes$number`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your expected output? You want to replace the values, add a new column, merge the data frames, or something else?

Comment: You should look into merging data in R. See the `merge()` function, or `inner_join` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following,

```
edges$from <- sapply(edges$from, function(i)nodes$number[match(i, nodes$names)])
edges
#    from   to
#1    1   James
#2    1 Gabriel
#3    2  Philip
#4    3 Gabriel
#5    3  Philip
```